# Openssl fipsld usage in static library

Tags: static, openssl, sha, fips, sha1sum

- I have build a `FIPS capable openssl` library.
- `Openssl` Version `1.0.2t` and `FIPS object module 2.0.16`.
- I was reading the user guide for `FIPS object module` which told that the last step in building a program with `FIPS capable openssl` was to use `fipsld` to link my program with `openssl` rather than `gcc/ld` as it computes `sha1sum` of `fipscansiter.o` using `fipsprelim.c`.
- After this I need to call `FIPS_mode_set(1)` which enables `fips` mode.
- This works if I am generating a executable. But in my project we provide a `static` library to our customers and we resolve all dependencies at our end, so we unpack `libcrypto.a` using `ar x libcrypto.a` and add all the `openssl` object files to our static library `libapi.a`.
- There is one class(`API_DigitalSignature.cpp`) which is build as a wrapper around `openssl` api for digital signature.

*Now the problem is I am confused on how should I use `fipsld` in my project because I am not generating a program but rather just an archive?*

Also I clarified with some security persons that unpacking `libcrypto.a` doesn't  affect `FIPS` validation unless we are changing any `ciphers`.

Comment: Yes but that static lib is to be linked in an *ELF* (otherwise it would simply be pointless), and there *fipsld* comes into play. Same as in *openssl* (the executable) case.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:
MacOS

```
FIPSLD_CC=gcc /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld -o fips_hmac fips_hmac.c /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a
```

Linux (Ubuntu)

```
FIPSLD_CC=gcc /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld -o fips_hmac fips_hmac.c /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -I/usr/local/ssl/include -ldl
```

Here, `fips_hmac.c` is a simple C program I wrote to test FIPS. You should specify paths for `fipsld` and `libcrypto.a` that are relevant for your system.

Please, note flag `-ldl` in Linux solution